# How to create a method that accepts an arbitrary instance variable and modify it in place?

Tags: python, class, oop

I haven't used classes in for a while and I am a bit rusty.
I would like to create a method that can modify any variable from an instance:

```
class classTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
        self.b=0

    def addN(self,x,n):
        x+=n

test = classTest()

print(test.a) # prints 1
print(test.b) # prints 0

test.addN(test.a,2)
test.addN(test.b,5)

print(test.a) # prints 1, but I want it to print 3
print(test.b) # prints 0, but I want it to print 5
```

So is there an easy way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: That doesn't work because integers are immutable. That method could work with mutable data types.

Comment: You aren't passing a *variable* to `.addN()`, you're passing a *value* (which indeed came from a variable, but the value knows nothing about that).  `x+=n` is merely changing a local variable, it has no effect outside of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve what you (maybe?) want. I don't think it's very useful, but there's a way to do it.

```
class classTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
        self.b=0

    def addN(self, var_name, n):
        val = getattr(self, var_name)
        setattr(self, var_name, val + n)

test = classTest()

print(test.a) # prints 1
print(test.b) # prints 0

test.addN("a", 2)
test.addN("b", 5)

print(test.a) # prints 3
print(test.b) # 5
```

Comment: Thank you! For clarification, I needed such a method because I use it as the command of a tkinter button (which modifiy several instance variables). 
There might be better way to do it, but your proposition works well in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, the most straightforward solution to me looks:

```
test.a = test.addN(test.a, 3)
```

For this you only have to change the addN method to:

```
def addN(self, x, n):
    return x+n

...
print(test.a)  # returns 4
```